# How do I write this Schematron validation test for XML snippet?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-validation, schematron

**I have an XML snippet as such:**

```
<AAA>
    <Field name="a"/>
    <Field name="b"/>
    <Field name="x"/>
    <User id="x" id2="f"/>
    <User id="y"/>
</AAA>
<AAA>
    <Field name="r"/>
    <Field name="z"/>
</AAA>
```

I need rule such that if the User tag exists, it should check to see if the Attribute values of **`id`** and **`id2`** exist under the name Attribute of a Field.

So in the first **`AAA`** tag, it will validate and give 2 errors because **`"f"`** doesn't exist as a field name and neither does **`"y"`**.

The AAA tags don't always have User tags, and the User tags don't always have both **`id`** and **`id2`**.

I've been messing around with some XPath expressions but to no avail.

Comment: Do you use Schematron with XPath 2.0 or 1.0? In XPath 2.0 you can easily write `some $user in User satisfies not($user/(@id, @id2) = Field/@name`.

Comment: That didn't quite do it.

Comment: Please show a complete input XML document. Thanks! Also, "that didn't quite do it" is not a very precise error message. What exactly did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use XPath 2.0, then you could write the following Schematron rules:

**ISO Schematron**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">

    <sch:pattern>
        <sch:rule context="User[@id]">
            <sch:assert test="@id = ../Field/@name">User ID does not exist as a field!</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>

        <sch:rule context="User[@id2]">
            <sch:assert test="@id2 = ../Field/@name">User ID2 does not exist as a field!</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>

</sch:schema>
```

I am assuming an input XML document that does not have a namespace. The assertion does not fail if a `User` element does not have one of those attributes in the first place or if an `AAA` element does not have a `User` element.

You did not say very clearly why Martin Honnen's suggestion did not work for you, so I list it here anyway. The rule would look like:

```
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:rule context="AAA">
        <sch:report test="some $user in User satisfies not($user/(@id, @id2) = Field/@name)">User ID does not exist as a field!</sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did it. I wasn't able to show a stacktrace or anything more specific because there isn't a way for me to debug my schematron assertions. I didn't know what I was getting back, but I knew what I was getting back was wrong.